# pic18f45550 usb problem

Tags: usb, pic, microchip

I am trying to build a very simple USB communication device using pic 18f4550 
with default mikroelectronica example with no change (only change with hardware that I don't have couple of 100nf attached with vusb so I replaced them with 470uf 
and I didn't put any pf with my crystal oscillator)

The hardware:
[image: Schematic for usb pic18f4550]

The code is working very will with Proteus simulation:

```
unsigned char k;
unsigned char userWR_buffer[64];

const char *text = "MIKROElektronika Compilers ER \r\n";
//**************************************************************************************************
// Main Interrupt Routine
//**************************************************************************************************
void interrupt()
{
  HID_InterruptProc();
}
//**************************************************************************************************
//**************************************************************************************************
// Initialization Routine
//**************************************************************************************************
void Init_Main()
{
        //--------------------------------------
        // Disable all interrupts
        //--------------------------------------
        INTCON = 0;                             // Disable GIE, PEIE, TMR0IE,INT0IE,RBIE
        INTCON2 = 0xF5;
        INTCON3 = 0xC0;
        RCON.IPEN = 0;                          // Disable Priority Levels on interrupts
        PIE1 = 0;
        PIE2 = 0;
        PIR1 = 0;
        PIR2 = 0;

        ADCON1 |= 0x0F;                         // Configure all ports with analog function as digital
        CMCON  |= 7;                            // Disable comparators
        //--------------------------------------
        // Ports Configuration
        //--------------------------------------
        TRISA = 0xFF;
        TRISB = 0xFF;
        TRISC = 0xFF;
        TRISD = 0;
        TRISE = 0x07;

        LATA = 0;
        LATB = 0;
        LATC = 0;
        LATD = 0;
        LATE = 0;
        //--------------------------------------
        // Clear user RAM
        // Banks [00 .. 07] ( 8 x 256 = 2048 Bytes )
        //--------------------------------------
}
//**************************************************************************************************

//**************************************************************************************************
// Main Program Routine
//**************************************************************************************************

void main() {
 char i;

  Init_Main();

  HID_Enable(&userWR_buffer, &userWR_buffer);

  Delay_ms(1000);
  Delay_ms(1000);
  while(1) {
    Delay_ms(1000);
    i=0;
    while(text[i]) {
      userWR_buffer[0]= text[i++];
      while (!HID_Write(&userWR_buffer, 1));
      }
    }

  Delay_ms(1000);
  HID_Disable();
}
//**************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Are you sure the hardware is working ? It sounds like you have taken some liberties with decoupling capacitors which might cause problems. Try asking on http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: iam sure of hardware and thank you for directing me to other site

Comment: What problem are you actually experiencing?  Device doesn't show up in the Device Manager?  Windows complains that the device is malfunctioning?  HID driver does not attach to device?  HID report doesn't work?  Device doesn't receive power?

Comment: 100nf is very different from 470uf.   Ditto @Paul R.

Comment: ok pc didn't feel any thing about device ?

Comment: What's the voltage on the VUSB line and the VCC line?

Comment: Do you have a pull-up on MCLR# ? Can you confirm that your the PIC is running your program at all?  You could add an LED to your circuit and toggle it on and off in the main loop.  If you'd like, I can send you a working hex file that does HID on PIC18F4550 (worked for me).  That may help you prove out your hardware.

Comment: nick pls send me you file and yes i have toggled led and it works but still with no luck to get it work ,by the way there are wired thing my toggling led get faster with pic16f4550 although same code work fine with pic16f877a

Comment: @SamyMassoud  Since, I don't know your e-mail address, let's do this.  Send me an e-mail, I'll respond with the file.  My e-mail address is on my home page (there's a link is in my StackOverflow profile).

Comment: i sent you mail check your inbox nick

Comment: @SamyMassoud I've replied with teh program attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't put any pf with my crystal oscillator

I don't think this will work. Check with an oscilloscope what happens on your crystal. Your device has simply no clock input so it never executes anything.

Comment: actually i have tested this Alot of time with other simple prog like light on/off and it works !

Comment: What was your configuration when using a simple prog? Did it use the extrnal XTAL or did it use an internal clock?

Comment: As the USB clock is derived from XTAL frequency You need to have a XTAL with specific frequency (see datasheet which frequencies work with USB high speed/USB low speed) and connect it to OSCON1/OSCON2 (your schematic looks wrong here, too). And you will definitely need the capacitors to get the XTAL started.